# Is there a complex number $c$ such that $c^n$ goes to 1 as n (which is real) goes to infinity?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is there a complex number $c$ such that $c^n$ goes to 1 as n goes to infinity?

What is my motivation for that? I learned some dynamical system (such as fibonacci series) are expressible in the form of matrices. In this case we can apply diagonalization and obtain a matrix of eigenvalues ($D$) for our model matrix $M = SDS^{-1}-$ Since it is straightforward to calculate powers of such a diagonal matrix, this gives us a lot info about this system. Lets think about a system which moves but starts to get slower and slower. This would happen when entries of the diagonal matrix, or lets say eigenvalues of the $M$, are such that when we take their power to infinity, they converge to 1. If eigenvalues are real this would only happen with $1$. But in this case $M$ would be the trivial identity matrix. So my question is if we can construct a matrix with nontrivial eigenvalues such that their power to infinity converges to 1, or formally,

$\lambda^n \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$

I appreciate any help thanks!

Edit: $\lambda$ has to be a complex number and $\neq 1$

Comment: How about $c=1$?

Comment: "If eigenvalues are real this would only happen with 1. But in this case M would be the trivial identity matrix." I look for something interesting

Comment: There is no other possibility.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose that $\lambda^n\to1$. Then $|\lambda|^n=|\lambda^n|\to1$. This forces $|\lambda|=1$.

So $\lambda=e^{i\theta}$. Now $$\tag1|e^{i(n+1)\theta)}-e^{in\theta}|=|e^{i\theta}-1|=2|1-\cos\theta|.$$ If $\{\lambda^n\}$ converges, then $\{e^{in\theta}\}$ is Cauchy. But the only way that $(1)$  can go to zero is that $\cos\theta=1$, so $\lambda=1$.